# Hosting NuGet repository via Apache / http server

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

Is there any way that I can setup and host a NuGet repository on an Apache or related http server?  I have code that I would like made available, and it turns out that I have an apache server as well.  I know that there are public places that I could publish to, but I was curious about my own.  Any ideas?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it i made a little nuget server with php. It works on apache with mod_rewrite and IIS: http://www.kendar.org/?p=/dotnet/phpnuget :)

Answer (score 3):

I needed this recently too and have started implementing it at https://github.com/grenade/apache-nuget-repo

There are some limitations, like you can't push to it (yet?). To have that, it'd need some server side upload handler and that would mean picking a technology like PHP, Node, Python, etc which compromises the current simplicity. I also haven't made any effort yet around NuGet api v3 support.

Right now it relies on some other copy process uploading the .nupkg files and triggering the manifest and html generators.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stopping you come creating a NuGet server that runs on Apache, but I don't think there's anything currently available that'll do this.

The command-line nuget.exe runs on Mono, but I suspect getting the ASP.NET NuGet server running is a whole new ballgame :-(

Comment: you ain't kidding.  I've done some research and it seems that I need an OData feed for starters.  That lead to some chatter on the web about a PHP implementation (I know there is a PHP SDK for OData), but I haven't dedicated the time to digging in.